# In Google sheets, I need a script to run on a form submit, but reference a separate sheet other than "form responses"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am trying to get a script to look at a named sheet in the workbook when a form is submitted. I used this script for a while and now need to add some calculations to the data that gets submitted. I have the form response data going to a sheet to add some calculations, then gets put in a doc and emailed out. The email doc function works great, just can not got the script to look at the data on the "Output" sheet vs. the "Form_Responses" sheet.

This is the script as it has been, I have tried several things but no luck, always pulls from "Form_Responses". I removed my trial code for clarity.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

### My code :

```
var docTemplate = "1oeUqdaesyHM-WzUTFIlzHFzAqIm1DN4OiiGywgs622w"; // template ID 
var docName = "Service Invoice";

function onFormSubmit(e) {
    var email_address = "<>";
    var email_address2 = "<>";
    var job_number = e.values[1];
    var date = e.values[2];
    var tech_name = e.values[7];
    var customer_name = e.values[3];
    var customer_email = e.values[6];
    var address = e.values[4];
    var phone = e.values[5];
    var work_description = e.values[9];
    var project_manager = e.values[8];
    var project_manager_email = "<>";
    var known_issues = e.values[10];
    var hours = e.values[11];
    var labor_total = e.values[21];
    var material_total = e.values[20];
    var total = e.values[22];
    var paid = e.values[15];
    var type = e.values[16];
    var check_num = e.values[17];

    var copyId = DriveApp.getFileById(docTemplate)
        .makeCopy(docName + ' for ' + job_number)
        .getId();

    var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);

    var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();

    copyBody.replaceText('keydate:', date);
    copyBody.replaceText('keyjobnumber:', job_number);
    copyBody.replaceText('keycustomername:', customer_name);
    copyBody.replaceText('keyaddress:', address);
    copyBody.replaceText('keyphonenumber:', phone);
    copyBody.replaceText('keycustomeremailaddress:', customer_email);
    copyBody.replaceText('keyemployeename:', tech_name);
    copyBody.replaceText('keyworkdescription:', work_description);
    copyBody.replaceText('keyprojectmanager:', project_manager);
    copyBody.replaceText('keyfollowup:', known_issues);
    copyBody.replaceText('keyhours:', hours);
    copyBody.replaceText('keylabortotal:', labor_total);
    copyBody.replaceText('keymaterialtotal:', material_total);
    copyBody.replaceText('keytotal:', total);
    copyBody.replaceText('keypaid:', paid);
    copyBody.replaceText('keypaymenttype:', type);
    copyBody.replaceText('keycheck:', check_num);

    copyDoc.saveAndClose();

    var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf");

    var subject = "ESCON Group Service Invoice";
    var body = "Please find attached your invoice for the service work performed by ESCON Group.";
    MailApp.sendEmail(customer_email, subject, body, {
        htmlBody: body,
        attachments: pdf
    });

    var subject = "ESCON Group Service Invoice" + job_number;
    var body = "Here is the Service Invoice for: " + job_number + "";
    MailApp.sendEmail(project_manager_email, subject, body, {
        htmlBody: body,
        attachments: pdf
    });

    var subject = "ESCON Group Service Invoice" + job_number;
    var body = "Here is the Service Invoice for: " + job_number + " -Please contact Trevor Gross with any questions.";
    MailApp.sendEmail(email_address, subject, body, {
        htmlBody: body,
        attachments: pdf
    });

    var subject = "ESCON Group Service Invoice" + job_number;
    var body = "Here is the Service Invoice for " + job_number + "";
    MailApp.sendEmail(email_address2, subject, body, {
        htmlBody: body,
        attachments: pdf
    });

    DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).setTrashed(true);
}
```

Comment: What values are you trying to get from the Output sheet?

Comment: I am using =filter to grab 15 columns from the "form_responses" sheet and drop them on the "output" sheet. I then have 3 more columns on the "output" sheet that calculate based on the data that comes from the form. Right now the script looks at all the e.values correctly, I just need it to look at the "output" sheet, not the "form_responses" sheet. Does that make sense?

Comment: Not really. I don't see where in your code you're trying to get any value(s) from the Output sheet, but look at my answer and let me know if that doesn't get you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

To get a value from a specific sheet, you need to get the spreadsheet (`e.source`), the sheet ([`getSheetByName()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)), the range ([`getRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation)), and then the value ([`getValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue)).

For example:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var outputSheet = e.source.getSheetByName("Output");
  var outputColumnA = outputSheet.getRange("A:A").getValues();
  var outputA1 = outputColumnA[0][0];
  console.log(outputA1);
}
```

Comment: I tried adding that and still get the data from the Form Responses sheet. I'm not sure what I am missing.

Comment: @JacobR Did you simply copy/paste that code or did you manipulate it to get the values you actually need?

Comment: I made changes to get what I needed ( I believe). It seems to jump right past it and go to the responses sheet. The script runs fine and outputs based on the information on the responses sheet. Only got a failure when I intentionally broke it. Could you insert it in my original code as you feel it needs to be and I will try it? (And see if I was following correctly) Is there another thought process I should be using other than;

 function onFormSubmit (e) {

 ver name = e.value [1]

Comment: I have used the basic outline of this several times and it has worked well but it's always just the responses sheet. I am learning as I go, I understand the logic, just don't know the code well enough yet. Thanks for your input

Comment: @JacobR I have no idea how it's supposed to be. You should post your revised code instead and include a more detailed description of what you're trying to do.